# Instantiate a new Python interpreter with xterm, but sharing the same Python stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, xterm

I am trying to create a Python shell in a Tkinter window.

I found this snippets that works well.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

root= Tk()

termf = Frame(root, width = 600, height = 400)
termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 80x20 -sb -e ipython &' % wid)
```

However, this snippet create a new Python interpreter (which start a new Python instance).

I would like **to be able to interpet the code with the Python process which is used to create the Tkinter windows** (**so I can access the same stack**).

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you ask in the way that you want. The way this works requires xterm, and an xterm process by definition must be a separate process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which way would you recommand therefore? The big picture is that I need to have a graphic canvas (using a refresh loop), and a side shell where I can modify what happens in my canvas